# Creating disk image while Windows is active

Tags: disk-image, windows-backup

I am used to creating disk images with Ghost, which I do with a Ghost CD that boots up by itself.  That process takes about 20 minutes.

I just started using a backup software called EaseUS, and that creates an image while Windows is active.  It takes much longer (around 90 minutes).  I am leery of an image that is created while Windows is active.  How is consistency achieved?  For example, the Registry would surely not be the same at the end of the 90 minute period, compared to when the backup started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is consistency achieved?

It's using [Shadow Copies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785914(v=ws.10).aspx), and taking a 'snapshot' of the live system to create an image from.

It will be accurate as of the time the snapshot (shadow copy) was created.

Comment: Is that one reason why the entire process is taking so long?

Comment: It's taking longer primarily because the OS (and any running applications, etc.) is still actively using the disks while the image is being created.

Comment: Windows Backup?  Other than that, no I do not.

Comment: In Linux `dd` can copy just about anything, and is free

Comment: @Sabuncu - Software recomendations are not on topic here at Superuser

Comment: @Ramhound OK, erased it.